# Leaflet map doesnt run mouse events

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a problem with a Leaflet map not responding to click events.
I add a map using the tutorial code:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    maxZoom: 19
}).addTo(mymap);

mymap.on('click', function(e) {alert('map click!')});
```

After this I get a nice responsive map. I can pan and zoom, but it doesnt respond to clicks.
What can cause it to not propagate events I register to ?

EDIT: When I add a marker and hover over it the tooltip added using bindTooltip() doesnt show and a popup added using bindPopup() doesnt show when I click on the marker.
It is as if the map doesnt propagate mouse events to registered handlers and doesnt respond to hover events.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your browser blocks alert popup.
Try 
`mymap.on('click', function (e) { console.log(e) });`

Comment: I've tried that. It simply doesn't call the function for some reason

Comment: try to copy code from this tutorial example as is and remove unnecessary parts https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html

Comment: When I run that exact code it works, however in my code, I dont change anything.
The difference is that I add a couple of elements after the map div

Comment: @Oberon: "_I add a couple of elements after the map div_" that _may_ explain things indeed, especially if you specify their position and add some click and mouseover event listeners with stop propagation. You should add the code to your question, making sure it reproduces your issue (use the SO code snippet feature, or other services like JSFiddle for example or https://leafletjs.com/edit.html)